# Обновление appWidget в Fragment

Tags: android

Привет всем. Есть проблема при создании виджета из собственного списка он не хочет реагировать на нажатия. Он добавляется в view, тут все ок.

```
public void createWidget(int id, AppWidgetProviderInfo appWidgetProviderInfo) {
AppWidgetHostView hostView = mAppWidgetHost.createView(activity, id, appWidgetProviderInfo);
            hostView.setAppWidget(id, appWidgetProviderInfo);
            view.addView(hostView);
}

@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAppWidgetHost.startListening();
        Log.e("onStart", "True");
    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mAppWidgetHost.stopListening();
        Log.e("onStop", "True");
    }
```

Я так понимаю должен существовать некий sendBroadcast на установку его обновления. Так как через это

```
public void createWidget(int id, AppWidgetProviderInfo appWidgetProviderInfo) {

Intent pickIntent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK);
              pickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, id);
              activity.startActivityForResult(pickIntent, 9);

AppWidgetHostView hostView = mAppWidgetHost.createView(activity, id, appWidgetProviderInfo);
            hostView.setAppWidget(id, appWidgetProviderInfo);
            view.addView(hostView);
}
```

все работает на ура! Только вместо использования моего списка виджетов открывается системное окно выбора виджета.